# How to copy image to clipboard, to paste to another application?

Tags: ubuntu, images, clipboard, compiz

I want to set the clipboard to file `abc.jpg`, in image format, so I can paste it to `gpaint`, etc. X11 applications, can I?

I have enabled Screen snapshot feature in `Compiz` windows manager, and I need to give a command line to copy the snapshot image file to the clipboard.

Answer (score 23):

## scrot + xclip

You can use `scrot` with `xclip` to take a screenshot and copy it to clipboard.

```
scrot '/tmp/%F_%T_$wx$h.png' -e 'xclip -selection clipboard -target image/png -i $f'
```

It will capture whole of your screen and copy the image to clipboard. If you want to capture current window then use `-u` flag. For selection of particular area, you can add `-s` flag. See `$ man scrot` for more options.

It will store your screenshot in `/tmp` directory. You can change that directory wherever you want it to get stored. Files from `/tmp` directory usually gets deleted after each reboot. If you want to immediately remove the stored file, then do something like:

```
scrot -w '/tmp/%F_%T_$wx$h.png' -e 'xclip -selection clipboard -target image/png -i $f && rm $f'
```

As I read in other comments, you need it for copying a screenshot to the clipboard. I hope this answers your question.

If you just need to copy an already existing image file to clipboard:

```
cat 2018-06-16-224938_670x730_scrot.png | xclip -selection clipboard -target image/png -i
```

You can set keyboard shortcuts/keybindings according to your current Desktop Environment/window manager.

---

#### Bonus

Explanation of `/tmp/%F_%T_$wx$h.png`:

It's being used as the file name. These are called `format specifiers`. They are of two type: starting with `%` or `$`.

```
%F     Equivalent to %Y-%m-%d (the ISO 8601 date format).

%T     The time in 24-hour notation (%H:%M:%S).
```

`%F_%T_` will print something like: `2018-06-17_02:52:19_` i.e. your current timestamp. You can customize the format as per your requirements. See `$ man strftime` for more help.

`$wx$h` are part of the scrot's internal specifiers.

```
$w   image width
$h   image height
```

So the final file name will look something like `2018-06-17_02:52:19_1365x384.png`.

Comment: What a great answer! Thank you kindly.

Comment: Or just use `scrot - | xclip -selection clipboard -target image/png`.

Answer (score 9):

First, install python, and pygtk

```
sudo apt-get install python pygtk
```

Now save the following script somewhere as imgclip.py (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571855/pasting-image-to-clipboard-in-python-in-linux)

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import os
import sys

def copy_image(f):
    assert os.path.exists(f), "file does not exist"
    image = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(f)

    clipboard = gtk.clipboard_get()
    clipboard.set_image(image)
    clipboard.store()


copy_image(sys.argv[1]);
```

To use it:

```
python /path/to/imgclip.py filename.png
```

Note: tested pasting in gimp and xournal.
Note: this is for gnome desktop (hence gtk). I bet there's something similar for kde

Answer (score 7):

Install `xclip` (be sure the version is 0.12+svn84, because 0.12 is not enough); then, add this line to the box in the compiz settings manager:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -target image/png -i
```

[image: Example in compiz]

You should then be able to paste it to any other x application

Answer (score 4):

Check out `xclip`. It allows you to move text, or files to the clipboard from the command line.

**EDIT**:

There are command-line screenshot apps discussed in this post: http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/57772 including `scrot`. This is from the `scrot` man page:

```
scrot  is  a  screen capture utility using the imlib2 library to aquire
       and save images.  scrot has a  few  options,  detailed  below.  Specify
       [file]  as  the  filename  to save the screenshot to.
```

One last option is to find an X app which just takes a screenshot when clicked (no prompts, dialogue boxes etc), assign it to a hotkey combination and use `xdotool` to simulate that keypress from the command line??

Comment: @OP, did you actually _need_ a command line tool, or are you just trying to get a screenshot into the clipboard? There's much easier way to go **that**

Comment: Yes, I need a command line tool.

Comment: Unfortunately, both `xclip` and `xsel` don't work with images, they work with text contents only.

Comment: Right, my bad, I didn't try pasting into a graphics program, I only tried `xclip < image.jpg` and `xclip -o > image2.jpg` which works, but is useless ;(

Comment: I tested scrot, it works nicely to get a screenshot straight out to a file, but it can't get it into the clipboard :/

Answer (score 3):

I'd disable Compiz's screenshot feature, just Head over to `System` -> `Preferences` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts` (under `Desktop` category) and bind <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> to `Take a Screenshot`

[image]

---

Now whenever you hit <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> a sreencapture will be taken with an option to copy to clipboard, or just to save the file.

[image]

Comment: No, I like the screen shot feature comes from `Compiz`.

Comment: A small question, how do you make the "Print Screen" button in SU?

Comment: @谢继雷 oh just put the the desired button between <kbd> &  </kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Command line solution

1. To just copy an image `IMG.png` stored at `$DESTINATION` as `$DESTINATION/IMG.png`, use

```sh
xclip -in -selection clipboard -target image/png $DESTINATION/IMG.png
```

Similarly for `IMG.jpg` change argument after `-target` i.e.,

```sh
xclip -in -selection clipboard -target image/jpg $DESTINATION/IMG.jpg
```

If you are taking a screenshot with `scrot` and want to save as well as copy it, use

```sh
# Enter path such as $HOME/Pictures/screenshots/ in $DESTINATION.
$DESTINATION = "/path/to/screenshot/folder/"
scrot "$DESTINATION/%Y-%m-%d-%T.png" &&
{
        SSNAME="$(ls -t $DESTINATION |head -n1)";
        xclip -in -selection clipboard -target image/png "$DESTINATION/$SSNAME" && echo "Copied to clipboard.";
}
```

> Note there is `&&` after `scrot` command.

`ls -t` will list and sort according to time. `head -n1` will filter only first result i.e., latest one.
`xclip -in` will tell xclip to take input from a file.

You can also give `xclip` command in `scrot` with an `-e` option.

Check [this](https://github.com/chhajedji/scripts/blob/master/screenshot.sh) script where I have used above mentioned snippet with `notify-send` (which is not a big deal :P).

Answer (score 1):

### Updated answer of @Mandeep Singh

---

You can use `scrot` and `xclip` to copy the image directly to clipboard.

Unlike Mandeeps solution, there is a way to copy the output directly to clipboard without ever writing it to disk.

### Example:

`scrot -fs - | xclip -selection clipboard -target image/png -i`

I typically use the `-fs` flags on scrot. `s` allowing me to capture a custom rectangle, and `f` freezing the screen while I select an area.

The lone `-` tells scrot to redirect output to stdout, allowing you to pipe it directly into xclip as shown in my example.

Comment: This is perfect! I had flickering problem in scrot while selecting an area. `-f` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Combining [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1331914/182897) with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500163/bash-script-with-scrot-area-not-working I use the following script now:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

tmpdir=$(mktemp --tmpdir -d scrot-xclip-XXXXXXX)
trap 'rm -rf "${tmpdir}"' EXIT

setxkbmap -option grab:break_actions
xdotool key XF86Ungrab

scrot "$@" "${tmpdir}"/'screenshot-%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.png' -e \
    'exec xclip -quiet -t image/png -selection clipboard -i $f'

echo "Clipboard got overwritten"
```

The idea is to remove the created file after the clipboard gets reused (`xclip -quiet` blocks until this happens). `mktemp` also makes sure no other user can read the screenshot file.

I hooked this as `/home/user/bin/scrot-xclip` into my [i3](https://i3wm.org/) config:

```
bindsym Print exec --no-startup-id /home/user/bin/scrot-xclip --select --freeze
bindsym $mod+Print exec --no-startup-id /home/user/bin/scrot-xclip --focused
```